# Does Mule offer hot-deployability for Camel routes?

Tags: java, mule, esb, middleware, hotdeploy

I have a Camel-heavy web application that suffers from chronic releases because business logic is always changing and we are constantly adding/modifying our routes.

I heard a co-worker talking about Mule ESB, and that it was Camel-compliant and allowed you to hot-deploy routes. After perusing Mule's website/online docs, I don't see any mention of either of these, but it definitely has my attention.

I would need Mule to allow me to convert my existing Camel routes into deployable units (like JARs, WARs, etc.), but then allow me hot-deploy or undeploy each "route JAR" as new business logic is added or modified. Does Mule do this, or was my co-worker a buffoon? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it would make more sense to convert your Camel routes to Mule flows, if you want to benefit from Mule application hot redeployment capacity.

Anyway, assuming you can package your Camel routes as Mule applications (and I have no idea how you will do that), you can then hot redeploy the routes if you would run the Mule applications that contain them in the Mule Standalone server.

Comment: Thanks @David Dossot (+1) - I guess I'm not understanding the difference between a Mule "flow" and a Mule "application". Does a Mule app consist of 1+ flows? Do flows exist independent of apps? Also, do Mule flows offer similar integration patterns to Camel? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. Yes, a Mule application (merely a Zip file) is composed of N flows. You can run Mule flows without packaging them in a Mule application if you embed Mule in an JavaEE webapp, but in that case you're losing the hot redeploy feature of Mule Standalone server. And yes, Mule flows offer similar integration patterns than Camel, though without strictly sticking to standard EIPs.

Answer (score 0):

Apache ServiceMix / Apache Karaf / Fuse ESB all offers hot deployment of Camel applications. You may also want to take a look at that. Then you don't need to migrate any Camel routes / code to a completely new server.

- http://servicemix.apache.org/
- http://karaf.apache.org/
- http://fusesource.com/products/fuse-esb-enterprise/